# Find XElement by Attribute value

Tags: attributes, linq-to-xml

I have a collection of IEnumerables and each one has a different attribute values that corresponds to a different property on my business object. Here is a sample of the XML that I am querying against:

```
  <SimpleData name="zip">60004</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="name">ARLINGTON HEIGHTS</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="state">IL</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="countyname">COOK</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="lat">42.1121336684356</SimpleData>
  <SimpleData name="lon">-87.9736682731814</SimpleData>
```

I think my linq2xml lambda is close (after searching MSDN and SO) but I can't seem to tweak it just right:

```
string cityName = simpleData.Where(a => a.Attribute("name").Value == "name").Select(a => a.Value).ToString();
```

The value of cityName get's assigned to "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.String]" instead of ARLINGTON HEIGHTS

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
string cityName = (simpleData.Where(a => a.Attribute("name").Value == "name")
                  .Select(a => a.Value)).FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
(from x in simpleData
where x.Attribute("name").Value == "name"
select x.Value).FirstOrDefault()
```

which returns an `IEnumerable<string>` (Linq extension methods almost always return collections and not single instances) containing all element values whose `name` attribute equals `name`.  Then we take the first one, or `null` if its empty.

Also, that XML is horrendous and should be shot.

Comment: I would suggest using `(string)Attribute("name")` over `Attribute("name").Value` - it's the same thing, except that it does a null-check first. Since `Attribute()` returns `null` when no attribute with such name exits on an element, the first such element would trigger a `NullReferenceException` in the query as currently written.

Comment: Damnit, I knew it was just one little thing I was missing, adding FirstOrDefault did it. Thanks.

Not much I can do about the XML, it's a 3rd party data import source.

Comment: 1) Buy a book on XML.  Any book.  2) Locate 3rd party. 3) Beat them bloody with said book.

Comment: That's not horrendous XML, it's just mildly annoying. "Horrendous" is when you have gems like `<order1>...</order1><order2>...</order2>...`. Or how about `<name_of_entity_encoded_in_tag>...</name_of_entity_encoded_in_tag>`?

Comment: Pav, delete your comment.  Don't give ANYBODY ANY HINT that such evil is even possible!

Comment: @PavelMinaev +1 for the string cast tip which avoids reams of null test logic.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the XML:

```
<SimpleDataList>
   <SimpleData name="zip">60004</SimpleData>  
   <SimpleData name="name">ARLINGTON HEIGHTS</SimpleData>  
   <SimpleData name="state">IL</SimpleData>  
   <SimpleData name="countyname">COOK</SimpleData>  
   <SimpleData name="lat">42.1121336684356</SimpleData>  
   <SimpleData name="lon">-87.9736682731814</SimpleData>
</SimpleDataList>
```

loaded in the XElement/XDocument SimpleDataList, you can query with XPath:

```
SimpleDataList.XPathSelectElement(@"//SimpleDataList/SimpleData[@Name=""name""]");
```

But I'm not sure if you have an XElement to start with or a simple IEnumerable... In any case.. i figured I'll mention XPath in case it helps you.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to use XPath to query `XDocument`, since it's specifically tailored to LINQ. XPath is going to be slightly slower, too (because it's a string that has to be parsed first).