# Returning in LINQ to XML

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

I am working with a method using LINQ to XML to return a string.This is the XML

```
       <data name="lnkViewResultResource1.Text" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>View results</value>
  </data>
  <data name="lnkVoteResource1.Text" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Vote</value>
  </data>
  <data name="number of results" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>You already {0} voted in this poll {1}</value>
  </data>
```

(I want to take the "name" attribute)
This is my method:

```
    Public Shared Function getlabel(ByVal filename As String, ByVal valuetrans As String) As String
    Dim label = From l In XElement.Load(filename).Elements("data") Where l.Element("value").Value = valuetrans Select (l.Attribute("name").Value).First
    Return label.ToString
End Function
```

And this is returning this :

System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.String]

I googled and used following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639653/find-xelement-by-attribute-value) FirstOrDefault(), but it didn't work in my case.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Alf.

Comment: The search you are doing in the result set is not necessary if your xml looks like that. It seems that you expect more data, could you please expand the <data> structure to what it will be? In that case it's easier to tell how the link expression should look like.

Comment: sorry, I just added a part to make it simpler. I update with the whole XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your call to 'First' is placed wrong, try this:

```
Dim query = From l In XElement.Load(filename).Elements("data") _ 
     Where l.Element("value").Value = valuetrans _
     Select (l.Attribute("name").Value)
Dim label = query.First()
Return label.ToString()
```

Comment: Yes! At first I thought it didn't work, but it did!! :) . Thank you for the answer, I was supposing something like this, but I didn't try it that way

Answer (score 1):

You can do it your way also, but you have to wrap the whole linq query in parens to do the first correctly:

```
Public Shared Function getlabel(ByVal filename As String, ByVal valuetrans As String) As String
        Dim label = (From l In XElement.Load(filename).Elements("data") 
        Where l.Element("value").Value = valuetrans 
        Select l.Attribute("name").Value).First
        Return label.ToString
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks!! I tried also to wrap it, but I didn't do it that way

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to use chaining:

```
var result = XElement.Load(filename).Elements("data")
    .First(l => l.Element("value").Value == valuetrans )
    .Attribute("name")
```